# Failing to query mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to use a form to query a mysql database in Ubuntu Server. The database is connecting but somehow the results are not being echoed as requested in the code. Here is my sample code

```
<?php
$var=$_REQUEST['IP'];
echo "$var";
mysql_connect('localhost','root','mysql','syslog')
or die("Unable to connect to the database");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arp_table");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
?>
```

I am sure it is connecting to the database because it is not displaying the die message, but it is not doing anything beyond dispaying the variable connected to the form.

Comment: `$row=mysql_fetch_row($result)`  missing a semi colon at the end, hence a parse error

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: You not have the semicolon in `$row=mysql_fetch_row($result)`

Comment: even the `mysql_connect` syntax is wrong the 4th parameter should be bool `$new_link`

Comment: The semi colon is not an issue, it was a typing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code you have provided, the parameters you have passed to mysql_connect are wrong.

```
resource mysql_connect ([ string $server = ini_get("mysql.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysql.default_user") [, string $password = ini_get("mysql.default_password") [, bool $new_link = false [, int $client_flags = 0 ]]]]] )
```

The 4th parameter is new_link not the name of the database. Try the following code -

```
<?php

    $var = $_REQUEST['IP'];    
    echo $var;

    mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "mysql" ) or die("Unable to connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db( "syslog" );

    $result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM arp_table" );

    $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result );

    print_r( $row );

?>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: it has given me an idea of where i was getting it wrong, a platform to work on. But it is producing the answer in the form Array([0]=>1 [1]=>2), is there a better way to get the answer without array i.i just need to see 1, and 2

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    // instance of pdo
    $config['db'] = array
    (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname' => 'syslog'
    );

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . 
    ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'],
    $config['db']['username'],
    $config['db']['password']);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

   // in another file where you are including the connection script call upon global
   global $dbh;
  // $query becomes a pdo object

        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `arp_table`");
    $query->execute();
    $result= $query->fetchAll();

        print_r($result);
  ?>
```